# Failed to start application WAS 8.5.5.10

Tags: websphere, java-7, websphere-8, websphere-traditional

My application failed to start with the below error on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.10 which was working on 8.5.5.5

```
[1/2/17 17:54:20:842 IST] 0000006f ecs           W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource org/reflections/scanners/MemberUsageScanner$1.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/reflections-0.9.10.jar
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
```

1. The application failes to start after deployment
2. The application failes to start when JVM starts
3. The same application is getting started manually from console.
4. When i put reflections-0.9.10.jar in shared library i am getting Failed to load webapp

   ```
   Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: null
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:177)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
   ... 73 more
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
   at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(Unknown Source)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
   ```

5.The application started when i move all the third party jars to shared libraries.

Comment: does the WAS process have read access to `reflections-0.9.10.jar` on the file system? Is it possible that the jar is corrupt or was compiled with a higher level of java than what is being used at runtime?

Comment: Verified the compiled version of reflections-0.9.10.jar and it has same version as other application .

Comment: Even after i place reflections-0.9.10.jar i have same issue Failed to load webapp

Answer (score 2):

upgrade to 8.5.5.11, issue fixed in latest fixpack
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI60902 
If you find any other solution in 8.5.5.10, please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

The SystemOut.log file for the application server will indicate which version of the Java (JVM) is in-use. Verify whether the version of the class files in reflections-0.9.10.jar is greater than the version of the server JVM.  The error you posted will occur whenever this condition is true.